FEM: structure is flatten when the length is long
I am trying to simulate the electric voltage distribution on a structure between lines with roughness.
The coordinates are like this file:
LERCoordList
First I use these packages:
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; Needs["FEMAddOns`"];

I have generated mesh using the LERCoordList as boundarymesh with this code
LERMesh =  ToElementMesh@
  ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> 
    Flatten[{#[[2]], Reverse@#[[1]], {#[[2, 1]]}} &@#, 1], 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[
      Partition[
       Range[Length[
         Flatten[{#[[2]], Reverse@#[[1]], {#[[2, 1]]}} &@#, 1]]], 
       2, 1], Flatten[{Table[2, Length@#[[2]] - 1], 3, 
        Table[1, Length@#[[1]] - 1], 3}]]}] &@Block[{Len = #}, 
 Select[#, #[[1]] <= Len &] & /@ LERCoordList] & /@ {100,1000,10000}

and result as below:
Show[#["Wireframe"], PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-10, 20}},ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ LERMesh


The figure above is the first 100 of 10000 length unit. For me the quality of the mesh is good.
However, when I tried to solve the Poisson equation based on these mesh with this code:
Voltage =  NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[V[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, DirichletCondition[V[x, y] == 10, ElementMarker == 1],    DirichletCondition[V[x, y] == 0, ElementMarker == 2]},  V, {x, y} \[Element] #]&/@LERMesh

, this is what I got plotted with this code (here I also extract the first 100 length unit):
MapThread[ DensityPlot[#1[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] #2,    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-10, 20}},    AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100,    ImageSize -> Medium] &, {Voltage, LERMesh}]


As shown in the figure, the Voltage is nicely solved in the 100 and 1000 case, however for the 10000 case the roughness seems disappeared.
Can anyone help me solving this?
Thank you.

What is LERCoordList?

@user21 it's the list with the points of the edge. I didn't paste it here since it's too long

@GenTleMen Please give some additional  information about the region you  want to mesh and how the plots are created. Thanks!

@GenTleMen, with out being able to reproduce what you have it's difficult / impossible to help.

@Ulrich Neumann the link of LERCoordlist file added. Thank you for your suggestions!

When I use LERCoordList = ToExpression[Import["LERCoords.txt"]]; I get a $Failed for your mesh generation. Unless you can provide a way to reproduce this it's not going to be easy to help. An alternative is to send a notebook to the tech support at wolfram.com

Also, you might want to comment on the difference in the V100 and V1000 case, I am not sure what you think is not right with the V1000 case. I do see an issue with the V10000 case. It would be good if you can state explicitly what you see and what you expect.

@user21 Hi, everything is updated and tested now. Could you try to use it and check if it works the same way as in the post? Sorry for the inconvenience.

@GenTleMen, unforunatly it does not work. I get lot's of error message and you have not included the "Import" command (or however) you get the coordinates.

@user21, I'm sorry and would like to make my codes work on your device. LERCoordList = ToExpression[Import["LERCoords.txt"]] is the way I imported. I use V14 and the codes are work fine without any other package activated.
Could you let me know in which step did you met the issue? Does it related to the Needs["NDSolveFEM"]; Needs["FEMAddOns`"];?

This: Block[{Len = 100}, Select[#, #[[1]] <= Len &] & /@ LERCoordList] gives part error message. Why don't you split the code into manageable chunks. I suspect some copy past error in the post. Open a new notebook and copy the code from this post and you will see the errors.
